# HTML / PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to code an all in one HTML/PHP contact from with error checking.
When I load this file in my browser there is not HTML. I am a newb php programmer so most likely forgot something pretty obvious.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>All In One Feedback Form</title>
</head>

<body>


<?
$form_block = "
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"op\" value=\"ds\">
<form method=\"post\" action=\"$server[PHP_SELF]\">
<p>Your name<br />
<input name=\"sender_name\" type=\"text\" size=30 value=\"$_POST[sender_name]\" /></p>
<p>Email<br  />
<input name=\"sender_email\" type=\"text\" size=30 value=\"$_POST[sender_email]\"/></p>
<p>Message<br />
<textarea name=\"message\" cols=30 rows=5 value=\"$_POST[message]\"></textarea></p>
<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Send This Form\" />

</form>";

if ($_POST[op] != "ds") {
 //they see this form
 echo "$form_block";

} else if ($_POST[op] == "ds") {


 if ($_POST[sender_name] == "") {
  $name_err = "Please enter your name<br>";
  $send = "no";
}

 if ($_POST[sender_email] == "ds") {
  $email_err = "Please enter your email<br>";
  $send = "no";
}

 if ($_POST[message] == "ds") {
  $message_err = "please enter message<br>";
  $send = "no";
}

 if ($send != "no") {
  //its ok to send
  $to = "jack@xxxxxxx.com.au";
  $subject = "All in one web site feed back";
  $mailheaders = "From: website <some email address@hhhh.com> \n";
  $mailheaders .= "Reply-To: $_POST[sender_email]\n";
  $msg = "Email sent from this site www.ccccc.com\n";
  $msg .= "Senders name: $_POST[senders_name]\n";
  $msg .= "Sender's E-Mail: $_POST[sender_email]\n";
  $msg .= "Message: $_POST[message]\n\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);

  echo "<p>Mail has been sent</p>";
}

else if ($send == "no") {
 echo "$name_err";
 echo "$email_err";
 echo "$message_err";
 echo "$form_block";
}

}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

FYI I am trying the example from a book named PHP 6 Fast and Easy Wed Development

UPDATE!!!

The code I see via view source is this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>All In One Feedback Form</title>
</head>

<body>



<input type="hidden" name="op" value="ds">
<form method="post" action="">
<p>Your name<br />
<input name="sender_name" type="text" size=30 value="" /></p>

<p>Email<br  />
<input name="sender_email" type="text" size=30 value=""/></p>
<p>Message<br />
<textarea name="message" cols=30 rows=5 value=""></textarea></p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send This Form" />

</form></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ouch! Maybe the book should be called *PHP 6 Fast and Easy, but hard to maintain, error-prone and riddled with security holes Web Development*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html with php as follows

```
<?php if ($_POST[op] != "ds") {  ?>

<input type="hidden" name="op" value="ds">
<form method="post\" action=\"$server[PHP_SELF]\">
```

/*  your html code here */

```
</form>";

<php } else if ($_POST[op] == "ds") {  ?>...............
```

Comment: hum... im a little confused. The example in this book I am using only has one open php tag <?php at the beginning of the form and one ?> close at the end of the script.

Comment: your html does not need to be in between php tags, in this example the user will also only see the html if op = ds because there was a php if before it. Therefor the 2 php parts <?php if(){ ?>HTML do be displayed if condition is met<?php } else ... ?>

Comment: wow that is right over my head, its my first week coding! how do I change the code?

Comment: instead of : 
if ($_POST[op] != "ds") {
 //they see this form
 echo "$form_block";
}
else { ... }
you can just do :
if ($_POST[op] != "ds") {
?>
<form method=\"post\" action=\"$server[PHP_SELF]\">
....
<?php
}
else {
...
}
then you can forget about the $form_block which will make things much cleaner :)

Comment: and indeed, like zaf said, all of your input needs to be between the <form> tags

Answer (score 3):

Try switching the tags

```
'<?' to: '<?php'
```

Your development environnement may not recognize short tags, thus producting an empty page.

When you access the source code of the page, do you see the doctype/html/body tags ?

Comment: Note that this is considered good practice - while it's possible to change your PHP installation to allow the short tags, generally it's best to just use the long format.

Comment: Hey thanks for the hlp, I tired adding <?php it didnt change anything, yes I can see the html source code, thanks again!

Comment: I just ran your code on my computer : I have some notices about empty indexes, but the form is shown.

Which php server do ou use ? Wamp ? easyphp ? 'hand-made' php server ?
Try to run a file with just < ?php phpinfo(); ?> to see if your php server is working as intended...

Comment: Hey Rodolphe I am runnign this os a hosts server, the phpinfo() works fine, it brings up all the php info. I can also see the form, the problem is that it wont process the form.

Answer (score 1):

Your left out some dashes when trying to access some of the $_POST and $_SERVER varibles.

Example: It's $_POST['op']  and not $_POST[op]

also $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]  and not $server[PHP_SELF]

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: server in /home/vidves/public_html/www01/test.php on line 14
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0011  111512  {main}( )   ../test.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: sender_name in /home/vidves/public_html/www01/test.php on line 16
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0011  111512  {main}( )   ../test.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: sender_email in /home/vidves/public_html/www01/test.php on line 18
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0011  111512  {main}( )   ../test.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: message in /home/vidves/public_html/www01/test.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0011  111512  {main}( )   ../test.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant op - assumed 'op' in /home/vidves/public_html/www01/test.php on line 25
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0011  111512  {main}( )   ../test.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: op in /home/vidves/public_html/www01/test.php on line 25
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0011  111512  {main}( )   ../test.php:0
```

Comment: Thanks PHP_Jedi

I checked my example in the book they have $_POST[op] and not $_POST['op'].

I changed $server[PHP_SELF] to $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]
Still doesnt work :(

Comment: Oki, could you please post in what you see on the screeen, than we can help you more. Do you get an errorcode or message, or is it just a blank page? ... A simple way to test where the code crashes is to uncomment and remove code bit by bit... please fill in with your result.

Comment: Thanks, but now im abit comfused here. Your question states that there is no HTML output from your script, and you have outdated with the output. So, Is your problem solved or what was the problem again?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
Your hidden input field is not inside the form tags and does not get sent when the form is submitted which does not trigger the rest of the PHP code.

So, instead of:

```
...
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"op\" value=\"ds\">
<form method=\"post\" action=\"$server[PHP_SELF]\">
...
```

Swap them round like::

```
...
<form method=\"post\" action=\"$server[PHP_SELF]\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"op\" value=\"ds\">
...
```

Very naughty.

Comment: well spotted, the script still doesnt run the error check e.g. no text in name field and return error.

Comment: If you just click submit on the blank form don't you get "Please enter your name" ?

Answer (score 1):

As a stylistic tip, you may want to read up on the [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) syntax. You could do your form building and variable assignment without all the escaping:

```
$form_block = <<<EOL
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="ds">
<form method="post" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">
<p>Your name<br />
<input name="sender_name" type="text" size=30 value="$_POST[sender_name]" /></p>
<p>Email<br  />
<input name="sender_email" type="text" size=30 value="$_POST[sender_email]"/></p>
<p>Message<br />
<textarea name="message" cols=30 rows=5 value="$_POST[message]"></textarea></p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send This Form" />
</form>
EOF;
```

Also be aware that blindly inserting user-provided data into the form as you are (sender_name and sender_email) can lead to trivial cross-site-scripting attacks. Consider what would happen if the user filled out the form and included a double-quote in either field, but caused a form error some other way (e.g: double quote in sender_name, but left sender_email blank). The double-quote gets inserted into the form and prematurely terminates the "value" attribute of the input field.

To mitigate this, pass all values that will be inserted into the form through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) first, which will escape any special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Some installations care about file-extensions, is your file called *.html or *.php?

It is not uncommon that *.html is just sent out to the client, while the *.php parsed by the php-engine and then to the client.

Comment: It's in .php formatt I tried changing it to .html and it had a whole lot of code printed on the screen, thanks for the suggestion.